# errors on apt-get install

Tags: apt

when I try to install a new package (for instance dafault-jdk) I get this error:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package lsb-base (--configure):

package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing: lsb-base
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've already searched google and this site, but nothing solved my problem.

When I try to run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

It ends up with the same error. 
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

EDIT:
I followed the hint, but when I try to it as described I'm getting the following result:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq lsb-base
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of lsb-base:
 cups depends on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14~).
 pulseaudio depends on lsb-base (>= 3.2-13).
 apport depends on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6).
 rsyslog depends on lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian3).
 hplip depends on lsb-base (>= 3).
 apparmor depends on lsb-base.
 avahi-daemon depends on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6).
 speech-dispatcher depends on lsb-base (>= 3.0-10).
 util-linux depends on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6).
 udev depends on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6).
 kerneloops-daemon depends on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14).
 cron depends on lsb-base (>= 3.0-10); however:
  Package lsb-base is to be removed.
 network-manager depends on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14).
 alsa-utils depends on lsb-base (>= 3.0-9).
 irqbalance depends on lsb-base (>= 3.1).
 cups-daemon depends on lsb-base (>= 3).
 anacron depends on lsb-base (>= 3.0-10).
 brltty depends on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14).
 initscripts depends on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14).
 kbd depends on lsb-base (>= 3.0-10).
 acpid depends on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14).
 unattended-upgrades depends on lsb
dpkg: error processing package lsb-base (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lsb-base
```

I still need help with this :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you get if you type `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: no errors, it runs as usual. or do you need the full output  (pretty long)